# how to connect printer to java application without using printer driver

Tags: java, printing

I am developing an application in  JAVA swing in which I have to use a printer to print receipt and my printer name is `EPSON thermal printer` model is `TM-TM-T88IV` (Running on parallel port `LPT1`).

I want to connect this printer in My JAVA app but the condition is that I don't want to install printer driver, I want to manually operate Printer. But have no idea how to start.

Comment: why not use the java api for printing?

Comment: You can start by writing a printer driver. Drivers are _required_ to provide an API to talk to hardware. Whether you _want_ to install one or not is not relevant.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your typing made me dizzy.

Comment: java api is useful whenever I will install printer Driver but I don't want to install printer driver

Comment: can i Use java pos for this task

Answer (score 2):

What you may want is to use Java Communications API. This API allows you to access Parallel port, serial ports etc.

Have a look at oracle site: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

Comment: Bro Thanks for your valuable response but I want to know that can I operate my printer through Java API without installing printer Driver please try to help me #KDM

Comment: This API doesn't require any driver as it connects directly to the LPT1 etc. Try it out and see whether it helps.

Comment: Hey KDM I used your valuable suggestion in my application ,its working properly but the problem is printer is getting the value but its not printing anything even its not print a blank page  and I want to know about how to send command to printer for printing anything if driver is not installed

Comment: Below I am posting my coding its working but not printing anything even printer is connected to my pc through LPT1 parallel port but I don't Want to install printer driver..i want to get a print directly from java coding